# Getting backend data in front reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting data from the backend to display it in the font like this

```
componentDidMount() {
  const response = this.props.store.privateImputationData;
  console.log(response);
}
```

It displays null in the console, now if i do a `setTimeout` it works!

```
componentDidMount() {
  setTimeOut(() => {
    const response = this.props.store.privateImputationData;
    console.log(response);
   }, 500);
 }
```

This how i m getting data from my store:

```
@computed get ImputationData() {
  return this.privateImputationData || {};
}
loadImputation = (diplayedImputations) => {
  HttpClient.postJSON(this.apiDataUrl, diplayedImputations).then((result) => {
    this.privateImputationData = result;
    this.loadAdditionalData();
  });
}
```

How can i do it without `setTimeout`?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Since the network request is asynchronous, the data will not have been loaded when your component first mounts, so it will not be set in `componentDidMount`. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i am trying to display the response data in the ui, the ui is in another component

Comment: Have you tried just using `privateImputationData` in your render method? It will re-render when `privateImputationData` is changed when the request is finished

Comment: when i do a console.log(this.props.store.privateImputationData ) in the render i get null

Comment: Yes, since it will not be set on first render, because your network request is not complete yet. You can check if `privateImputationData` is set, and if it is, you can do your logic.

Comment: how can i set privateImputationData after the first render ?

Comment: It will be set in the response of your network reqeust. `this.privateImputationData = result;`. If you just code the render method to have in mind that `privateImputationData` can be `null`, it will work.

Comment: what can i code in the render im in a lack of ispiration here ?

Comment: Something like `render() { if (!this.props.store.privateImputationData) { return null; } else { /* Do what you want when privateImputationData is loaded */}  }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the state object: [State and Lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html). Whenever the state changes, whatever component uses it, get's updated too.

```
this.state = {privateImputationData: null} //or some default
```

So in your code:

```
@computed get ImputationData() {
    return this.privateImputationData || {};
  }
  loadImputation = (diplayedImputations) => {
    HttpClient.postJSON(this.apiDataUrl, diplayedImputations).then((result) => {
    this.setState({privateImputationData: result});
    this.loadAdditionalData();
  });
}
```

To use the value:

```
this.state.privateImputationData;
```

Comment: i was missguided by an expert who told me that the state can't have data on it, 
it works now !  Thank you